# Swift 2. Cannot get UITableViewCell to populate

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I am still very new to coding and I am working on creating a cookbook app thinking it should be fairly simple.  I have been working on it for a while and have been able to stumble my way around getting it going by youtube videos, a course on udemy, and bits of code I find on here and github.  I have now run into a snag and I cannot find the answer.

I have 2 recipes entered and I am trying to get the recipe name to populate the tableview when I run my app but it is still blank.  I know it is most likely something simple and I have tried about everything.  I feel like it is in the "cell.textLabel?.text = recipe.name" line of code, but I am not sure.  This is the code I have so far

```
import UIKit

class tableVC: UITableViewController {

  var recipes: [AnyObject] = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let recipe0: Recipe = Recipe()
    recipe0.name = "Number 1"
    recipe0.ingredients = ["Pasta","Pasta Sauce","Hamburger"]
    recipe0.directions = "Cook pasta to directions on box, brown hamburger, add sauce to hamburger, dump on pasta"

    let recipe1: Recipe = Recipe()
    recipe1.name = "Number 2"
    recipe1.ingredients = ["all kinds of stuff","Then a dash of salt"]
    recipe1.directions = "enjoy"
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return recipes.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let recipe: Recipe = recipes[indexPath.row] as! Recipe

    cell.textLabel?.text = recipe.name

    return cell
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

  }
}
```

my Recipe file looks like this

```
class Recipe: NSObject {
var name = String()
var ingredients = [AnyObject]()
var directions = String()
}
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't add your recipes to your `recipes` array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating some `Recipe` objects in `viewDidLoad` but you aren't actually adding them to your `recipes` array -

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let recipe0: Recipe = Recipe()
    recipe0.name = "Number 1"
    recipe0.ingredients = ["Pasta","Pasta Sauce","Hamburger"]
    recipe0.directions = "Cook pasta to directions on box, brown hamburger, add sauce to hamburger, dump on pasta"

    let recipe1: Recipe = Recipe()
    recipe1.name = "Number 2"
    recipe1.ingredients = ["all kinds of stuff","Then a dash of salt"]
    recipe1.directions = "enjoy"

    self.recipies=[recipe0,recipe1]
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank You this works perfectly!  I know it was something simple that I was overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your class like this, change the array recipes to hold Recipe object only and add them after you create them.

```
import UIKit

class tableVC: UITableViewController {

var recipes: [Recipe] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let recipe0: Recipe = Recipe()
recipe0.name = "Number 1"
recipe0.ingredients = ["Pasta","Pasta Sauce","Hamburger"]
recipe0.directions = "Cook pasta to directions on box, brown hamburger, add sauce to hamburger, dump on pasta"
recipes.append(recipe0)

let recipe1: Recipe = Recipe()
recipe1.name = "Number 2"
recipe1.ingredients = ["all kinds of stuff","Then a dash of salt"]
recipe1.directions = "enjoy"
recipes.append(recipe1)

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return recipes.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = recipes[indexPath.row].name

    return cell
  }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You!  I also tried this out, and it works exactly how I want it to!

Answer (score -2):

There are multiple possibilities what can go wrong. Best place to check is the datasource.

```
 let recipe: Recipe = recipes[indexPath.row] as! Recipe
 if(recipe.name)
  cell.textLabel?.text = recipe.name
```